# Inductor voltage not decaying to 0V by t=5 TC

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, oscilloscope, waveform, function-generator

In a new lab I have the following circuit:

[image]

The inductor will change from 200 mH -> 400/600/800 mH.  I am starting with 800 mH.

The function generator is a square wave at:
50 Hz, 20 ms period, and 500 mV amplitude.

Most information on the internet and other questions I have looked up are concerned with \$t=0\$ inductor behavior.

I am familiar with the inductor voltage equation of $$V = L\frac{\mathrm{d}i}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

And when the square wave switches (\$t=0\$), there is an instantaneous jump in the inductor voltage.  I expected, however, that after 5 TC, inductor voltage would be 0 since the rate of change of current is 0 until the next edge of the square wave.  Instead, I am getting spikes of 1 volt at the square wave edge, but a decay of only 50 0mV.  Consequently, the resistor is only changing by 500 mV.  Why is my inductor not reaching 0 V?

The yellow trace is measured across the resistor (CH1 probe between Function Gen supply and resistor), and the blue trace is measured across the inductor (CH2 probe between resistor and inductor).

[image]

The 0 ms trigger is on the falling edge of the input square wave:

[image]

Comment: I suspect that the voltage did not drop to 0V due to inductor wire resistance.